# Show Snackbar above to showModalBottomSheet Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

I have showModalBottomSheet to get OTP code, If the user enter wrong code, I want to show snackBar. So, I used this method,

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        isDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 30, vertical: 0),
                      child: Column(children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: codeController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                          child: CustomButton(
                              onTap: () async {
                                if (codeController.text.length == 6) {
                                  try {
                                    PhoneAuthCredential credential =
                                        PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                                            verificationId: verificationId,
                                            smsCode:
                                                codeController.text.trim());
                                    await _auth
                                        .signInWithCredential(credential);
                                    Navigator.of(context)
                                        .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                            '/home',
                                            (Route<dynamic> route) =>
                                                false);
                                  } catch (e) {
                                  // ---------------------------------------------- 
                                  //this snackbar 
                                     showSnackBar(
                                           context,
                                           "Invalid verification code",
                                          "Please enter correct verification code");
                                    }
                                  }
                              },
                              text: "Continue",
                              height: 50),
                        )
                      ]),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
```

The snackBar showing under the showModalBottomSheet, So I want to show the snackBar above to showModalBottomSheet without hiding showModalBottomSheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use another `Scaffold` to get new  `ScaffoldMessenger` from `showModalBottomSheet` instead of top level.

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    isDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold( //here another scaffold
          body: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 30, vertical: 0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            const SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
                                content: Text(
                                    "Hey, I am above BottomSheet"));
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                          },
                          child: Text("show SnackBar"),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [`Scaffold`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) widget,

Comment: Hey, @Yeasin, i'm facing the same problem as the one showed in this question. Your aswer worked for me as well, but with one downside... Using scaffold makes my bottom sheet take the whole screens' height... is there anything I can do to prevent scaffold from taking all available height and use only enough to show the content ? Thank you.